# sql server monitoring for no activity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Server database that receives measurement records every 10 seconds form a sensor  on a machine in our production line. I need to monitor the tables to know if and when they DO NOT receive inserts from this sensor. I know how to monitor activity but how do I monitor lack of activity?

Comment: How do you monitor activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from measurement where datediff(ss, lasttime, getdate()) < 10
```